# reduce roscore startup time

Tags: ros, time, roscore, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm running ros on an embedded system (2xCortexA9@900MHz). It takes about 13 seconds till roscore is ready.
The problem is, that I need a running system with roscore and some small nodes after about 12 seconds. The bootup time of the operating system (~3sec) is included, so roscore must be started in 9 sec. or better.

I used the python cProfile module and runsnake but I didn't find the "one" time consuming element.
Are there any ideas how to reduce the startup time of roscore? Is it possible to "compile" roscore (binary without python)?

Thx!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179200/reduce-roscore-startup-time/) by [GringoRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/19194/gringoros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that there's an option to roslaunch that skips the disk space check; that may be able to shave a few seconds off of the startup time, particularly if there isn't a user to see the results.

UPDATE:

The command-line option to roslaunch to skip log size checks is `--skip-log-check`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AustinXDLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30664/austinxdliu/) on 2017-06-07**:
Thanks a lot for your great advice! May I know if there is any tips for finding the function of disk space checking in the source code of ROS? :)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-07**:
I've updated my answer with the option in question. If you're still curious about how it works, I'd recommend that you start at the roslaunch wiki page and follow the source code link to the source code.